# How can I avoid dependencies between methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following method:

```
protected ArrayList<String> prepInstaller(RemoteSession session) {
    ArrayList<String> installCommand = new ArrayList<String>();
    installer.setInstallOption(getCommand());
    installer.setInstallProperties(generateInstallProperties());
    installer.setTestHome(getTestHome(session));

    switch (installer.getInstallOption()) {
    case ("addon"):
        installer.setAddOnScriptPath(getAddOnScriptPath(session, true));
        installer.setAddOnImageLocation(getAddOnPath(session, true));
        installCommand.add(installer.getInstallCommand());
        break;
    case ("install"):
        installer.setImageLocation(getImageLocation(session, true));
        installCommand.add(installer.getInstallCommand());
        break;
    case ("patch"):
    case ("rollback"):
        installer.setPatchLocationPath(getPatchPath(session, true));
        for(String currentPatch: installer.getPatches()) {
            installCommand.add(installer.getInstallCommand(currentPatch));
        }
        break;
    }

    return installCommand;
}
```

My problem is that this line:

```
installCommand.add(installer.getInstallCommand());
```

contains `installer.getInstallCommand()` which will contain null objects unless the following are run:

```
installer.setInstallOption(getCommand());
installer.setInstallProperties(generateInstallProperties());
installer.setTestHome(getTestHome(session));
```

among others... The method has dependencies on previous methods being run which is not desirable. I have defined `installer` as a static factory:

```
public static InstallData getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new InstallData();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I have looked at using the builder pattern but it seems a bit unwieldly. I couldn't find a tidy version of it. I don't want to use a constructor, as it will be messy and I will need several of them.

I have also tried to construct an object containing all of the `set` methods and then passing the object into a new class which returned `getInstallCommand()`, but that got quite messy also.

Ideas welcome :)

Comment: It pretty much seems that `installer` is already some kind of `Builder`. You might be able to tidy things up by having some meaningful whole objects (group highly cohesive data into single concepts), but I do not know your domain enough to propose such groupings. Still, what about something like `String command = new InstallCommandBuilder(installOptions, installProperties, testHome).forAddon(scriptPath, imagePath).build();`

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly what I did in the end - I used an InstallCommandBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is pointed out in the question, it is not a desirable behaviour for an object to be instantiated or a method to be called while the object is in an illegal state. In most cases where an object creation requires 4 or more arguments but there can be reasonable defaults for some of them, the telescoping constructor (anti)pattern can be used by requiring the necessary arguments and substituting optional ones.

In other cases, especially if the arguments are of a similar/same type the builder pattern is used. Instead of specifying all parameters at once, they are set one by one and finally the `Builder` object is used to instantiate the desired class.

The question refers to "messy" code on a few occasions. While this is true for arbitrary code, a design pattern [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

> a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a
>   given context in software design.

Hence, if properly implemented it either works for the use case or it doesn't but it shouldn't be "messy". I'd also recommend having a look at java implementations of commonly used [design patterns](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns). Perhaps, a more suitable alternative can be found that fits in the question domain.

Comment: The design patterns link from github is excellent - thank you very much. Implementation of builder pattern there is very good.